# I took pity on a new site member over a low quality post

Tags: discussion

(S)he asks a very entry level **[question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/360530/fortran-in-fedora-linux)** that could be easily answered if they spent a few minutes looking over the Fedora 'getting started guide'. In fact, I mentioned exactly that.

Then I checked, and realized the Guide is currently offline. I decided to post the quick answer and explain why the post was low quality (-3 at that point).

This may be seen as polite and kind, but is it a good idea or does it undermine the intent of posting guidelines? Specifically, https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask and the guidance to Search for an answer before asking.

Comment: The only thing that makes it a "low quality" question is the missing info on what version of Fedora is used. I'll agree that it's a "level entry" issue though, but by assuming good intent, one must assume that some effort has gone into looking for a solution and answer accordingly without judgement. This is my personal opinion at least.

Comment: When I once answered a very entry level question, I got shot to pieces by people saying I was doing it for the rep. Stackexchange has a nasty habit of double standards with one side usually being okay helping newer people out in a softer way, and the other side ready to downvote any post showing a minor fallacy to hell.

Comment: I clicked your link to the question and got [this](https://i.imgur.com/krbuqdS.png). :/

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yeah, that sort of thing is better said in a comment. It isn't answering the question, so it doesn't really belong in an answer.

In general, we try to have answers answer the question and nothing else. No chit chat, as the help center says. So yeah, a comment would be better for this sort of thing.